# Acc decreasing to zero in LSTM Keras Training

Tags: python, keras, lstm

While trying to implement an LSTM network for trajectory classification, I have been struggling to get decent classification results even for simple trajectories. Also, my training accuracy keeps fluctuating without increasing significantly, this can also be seen in tensorboard:

Training accuracy:

[image: Training accuracy]

This is my model:

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(LSTM(8, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(40,2)))
model1.add(LSTM(8,return_sequences=True))
model1.add(LSTM(8,return_sequences=False))
model1.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))`
```

and my training code:

```
model1.compile(optimizer='adagrad',loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

hist1 = model1.fit(dataScatter[:,70:110,:],outputScatter,validation_split=0.25,epochs=50, batch_size=20, callbacks = [tensorboard], verbose = 2)
```

I think the problem is probably due to the data input and output shape, since the model itself seems to be fine. The Data input has (2000,40,2) shape and the output has (2000,1) shape.

Can anyone spot a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
model1.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))`
```

to:

```
model1.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))
```

The TimeDistributed applies the same Dense layer (same weights) to the LSTMs outputs for one time step at a time.

I recommend this tutorial as well https://machinelearningmastery.com/timedistributed-layer-for-long-short-term-memory-networks-in-python/ .

Comment: Thank you, but adding this layer gives me an assertion error for:     163     def build(self, input_shape):
--> 164         assert len(input_shape) >= 3

Answer (score 0):

I was able to increase the accuracy to 97% with a few adjustments that were data related. The main obstacle was an unbalanced dataset split for the training and validation set. Further improvements came from normalizing the input trajectories. I also increased the number of cells in the first layer.